# Do not see Event object in Dataloader

Tags: data-loader, activities

I need to move events from one SF instance to another, but when I open Data Loader I don't see Even (and Event Relation) object in the list of available options. I login under user with System Administrator profile.

P.S.: Task object is available.

[image: Data Loader objects]

Comment: Did you happen to "rename" the Event object, by chance? The data loader sorts by the label, not by the API name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the developers on the project renamed the Label of the Event object. Thank you @sfdcfox.

Comment: You're welcome!